How to Configure SSRS Web Service URL and Web Portal URL via Command Line
I need to apply the default settings on SSRS Web Service URL and Web Portal URL, but i need to do it automatically somehow.
Is it possible to do it via command line?
I have looked through this SSRS documentation from Microsoft, but don't see any option to do that.
As per Microsoft, You must write custom code that makes calls into the Report Server WMI provider. There are no command line utilities or script templates for configuring the URLs.

To configure Web service/Portal URL via command line you can achieve these by either using ReportingServicesTools module or editing the rsreportserver.config file.

For the ReportingServicesTools module, install the Powershell module if it is not installed:

Install-Module -Name ReportingServicesTools

This module will allow you to use the Set-RsUrlReservation cmdlet to configure the Web Service/Portal URL:
To Set Web Service URL:
Set-RsUrlReservation -ReportServerUri "http://yourserver:80/ReportServer" -RsConfigurationFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS14.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config"

To set Web Portal URL:
Set-RsUrlReservation -ReportPortalUri "http://yourserver:80/Reports" -RsConfigurationFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS14.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config"

Then restart the SSRS service.

Editing the rsreportserver.config file. This file is usually located on the Reportserver folder. You will need to edit the <UrlReservations> section for the Web Service/Portal URLs:

<UrlReservations>
  <ReservedUrl>
    <Url><http://+:80/ReportServer</Url>> #the Web Service URL
  </ReservedUrl>
  <ReservedUrl>
    <Url><http://+:80/Reports</Url>> #the Web Portal URL
  </ReservedUrl>
</UrlReservations>


Once done, save the file and restart the SSRS service.
Follow this documentation link and this for more.
